# Update UI element from thread

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I try to create in windows phone timer which update every 10-15 ms (for UI element). And i want have opportunity to append time. So i create TimeSpan and DispatcherTimer where interval = 15 ms. So every 15 ms call the event where i subtract 15 ms to timeSpan and when timespan <= 0 i call some method. When i set TimeSpan 4 seconds (for example) in life passed more than 4 sec about 4,6 sec. Also i tryed to use async/await but this did't work. I tryed to use System.Threading but i don't know how to update element which was create in the other thread.

Comment: Why are you using 15ms interval instead of the whole time that you want to wait (4 seconds if I understand correctly)? Invoking in the UI thread takes some time, so I guess that's what causing the delay/inaccuracy. Also, using async/await should work.

Comment: i update every 15 ms for user. it looking nice. So i using async await 
`async Task<bool> calculateTime()
        { timeRemaining -= TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(tic);}`
Than
`async void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {var a =   await calculateTime();}
               `

Comment: where tic = 15
timeRemaining = 4000

Comment: Could you please put the code in the question, as the formatting will be a lot nicer. Also, calculate time does not seem to be returning a bool or a Task<bool>? And another question: what do you update every 15ms - some UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
So every 15 ms call the event where i subtract 15 ms to timeSpan and when timespan <= 0 i call some method.
```

Your logic is flawed. You can't possibly update your timespan this way because:

1. As Stephen Cleary mentioned in his answer, you have no guarantee that the timer will  fire at exactly 15 ms
2. Even if it did, it doesn't take into account the time needed to actually update your timespan (say that it takes 1ms to compute the new timespan, your timer will drift of 1ms every 15ms)

To have an accurate time, you need to store the timestamp at which you started it (retrieve it by using `DateTime.UtcNow`. Every time your timer tick, take the new timestamp and substract to the one you saved. This way, you know exactly how much time has passed and your timer will never drift.

```
private DateTime start; // Set this with DateTime.UtcNow when starting the timer

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Compute the new timespan
    var timespan = DateTime.UtcNow - start;

    // Do whatever with it (check if it's greater than 4 seconds, display it, ...)
}
```

Comment: Ohh I'm fool (:
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

> So every 15 ms call the event where i subtract 15 ms to timeSpan

And there's your problem.

When you set a timer on any Windows platform, you can't expect a huge level of precision. On the desktop I believe the normal scheduler period on consumer hardware is ~12ms (and of course other apps can throw that off considerably). I have no idea what the scheduling is like on the phone but I assume it's less accurate than desktop (for battery lifetime reasons).

So, you simply can't approach this problem that way on Windows, because you can't assume that a timer will fire every 15ms. Instead, just start the `DispatcherTimer` to the full time span that you need, e.g., 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to update UI element in your timer thread

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            //Update Your Element.
        });
```

Comment: BeginInvoke is worked but time more than time in life